# Is "readonly" meaningful on a getter-only ref struct property in an interface?

Tags: c#

If I have an interface that specifies `ref readonly` on a property that only has a getter, is this `readonly` in any way meaningful, i.e. is it redundant?

```cs
struct Foo
{
}

interface IBar
{
    ref readonly Foo F { get; }
}
```

Comment: If you just want a readonly property then remove the `ref` and `readonly`

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured it out.

The getter returns the reference to a referred variable. If the `ref` is not declared as `readonly`, the caller that got the reference can still modify the variable. So, yes, `readonly` is meaningful.

I think the case where `readonly` is redundant only when the struct itself is already declared as `readonly`.

Answer (score 0):

There `ref` and *interface* here are superfluous... In any-case you are getting a `ref` regardless in your example. The only significant difference omitting `readonly` would make on a `get` only property within a *non-readonly struct* is with the `in` parameter, the *compiler* will make a defensive copy of the parameter for each *instance member* invocation

As [shown here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFDKgZgAQYM4BcBOArgMa4YBiA9pcgN7JYYAO+AlgG4CGuAphvj07BKAOwA2ATwysRuANoBdDAH1O+fJykBuBlnQVqAChnylajVICUGALwA+Fec22MTiVsZZdGfQKGjJfh4AM2lZDFwAC1ZsORNpJXsg0NV1TTiFHSQAX1RMHAISMipKGDpvFg5uPj9hcSkTRUc07W99EphjWSa3DGsk1IsXNw9PNvyBUPiomLjw1kSHSeaLDKzclCR9WAwAYXKkRn1gsUpuDABZLoNKDC4xQh5Lb3pDzx8AdjvOB545AAYlGBvr85HBMt4NkdMCczmQLp0ZDcYCDHs83hhXu9Pqi/oCMMD7o8wRCMRtskA==)

**Given**

```
public struct Foo
{
   private readonly int[] _array ;
   public Foo(int[] array ) => _array = array;     
   public readonly ref int this[int i] => ref _array[i];
}

public  struct Foo2
{
   private readonly int[] _array ;
   public Foo2(int[] array ) => _array = array;     
   public ref int this[int i] => ref _array[i];
}

...

public float M(in Foo value) => value[0] + value[1];

public float M2(in Foo2 value) =>  value[0] + value[1];
```

The emitted *IL* would  equate to

```
public float M([In] [IsReadOnly] ref Foo value)
{
    return value[0] + value[1];
}

public float M2([In] [IsReadOnly] ref Foo2 value)
{
    Foo2 foo = value;
    int num = foo[0];
    foo = value;
    return num + foo[1];
}
```